# Collecting a referenced app's values

Tags: podio

I am trying to cleanup and optimize my come I am running on podio's API. What I am currently doing is using the filter query to return a collection from one app. I then loop over that collection. On each item I use Podio get_field_value to return the value(s) of a field in a referenced app. This creates a lot of API calls. I would like to retrieve everything in one API call Here is a simple version of my current code:

```
 $collection = PodioItem::filter(WHSE_ID, array(
    "filters" => array(
        WHSE_EQUP_STATUS => array(2),
        ),
        "sort_by" => WHSE_LOAD_IN,
        "sort_desc" => false,
        "limit" => 50       
        )

    ); 

foreach ($collection as $item) {

    // Table-A ID
    $whId = $item->item_id;

    // Referenced App Item(s)
    $nucId = $item->fields[0]->values[0]->item_id;      

    // Get Referenced App Item Field            
    $app_b_value = PodioItem::get_field_value($nucId, NUC_LOAD_OUT);

    echo $app_b_value; 


    }
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this? I am thinking inline with the way you would use JOIN in a mysql query.

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to get value from each item from filtered collection, you don't need to make podio calls each time.

Podio filter call will give you item with values. you just have to get value from each item.

like following

```
foreach ($podioFilterData['items'] as $itemData) {
        $itemFields = $itemData['fields'];
            foreach ($itemFields as $field) {
                   $value =   $field['values'][0];
                }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the help.

I understand what you are talking about and I am doing that currently. My situation is this. I have two apps, A and B. In app A, there is a reference to app B. I am filtering the values from A. I need all those values plus two values from the referenced app.

Comment: When you do a filter items you will get basic item values. So for a reference field you will get item id of that referenced item. 

There is two way for you to do. 

First: 
Call filter item on app A. 
Loop through items in A and call Get item for the reference field. 

Second:
If you dont have bulk amound of data, 
You can call filter item on both A and B on first time. Then loop through A and select item from B list

Forbeach filter item it cost only 1 api call.  You can get max 500 items in one call. So if you have 2000 items it will cost you 4 calls only.